# TryParse: which value is set in case of error?

Tags: c#, .net

The signature of TryParse method for int (others are the same) is the following:

```
public static bool TryParse(string s, out int result)
```

where "out" means that result must be initialized even in case the parsing is not successful. Is it documented to which values TryParse(s) set variables in case of unsuccessful parsing?

I need to initialize some values to parsed values or to default values in case of unsuccessful parsing, in case of guaranteed default values I don't even need to check the result.

Comment: My guess would be the default value for the type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it documented to which values TryParse(s) set variables in case of unsuccessful parsing?

[Yes, it's documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx).

> *result*
>   When this method returns, contains the 32-bit signed integer value equivalent to the number contained in s, if the conversion succeeded, or zero if the conversion failed.

Comment: Indeed, for integer it is clearly documented, I missed it because actually I'm interested in Guid.TryParse and took integer as a simpler example. For Guid there is nothing in msdn documents, I can guess it should be Guid.Empty.

Comment: @ElDog In the [4.5 version of the doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.tryparse.aspx) is said that `Guid.Empty` is returned if the function returns false.

Comment: @ElDog: If you're actually interested in Guid.TryParse, it would have been useful to specify that instead of giving the Int32.TryParse signature... in which case I'd have linked to the latest documentation for that, instead.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: you are right. Anyway, I consider the question answered, thanks!